# Can we get " Weekly Newsletter " on daily basis or on every alternate day?

Tags: discussion, support

I find these mails really very knowledgeable, so just want to now can we get those mails at least twice in a week. Because we can improve our knowledge by reading those mails.

Comment: Our volume isn't that high, why not just read the site daily? Or subscribe to a tag feed or two?

Comment: @waxeagle why don't you add that as an answer?